# Get only rows where 2 conditions are fulfilled in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which is a mapping table t1. It looks like the following:

```
+-------+---------+-------------+
| Reqid | FIELDID | LISTITEMID  | 
+-------+---------+-------------+
|  219  | 76      |    3548     |
|  219  | 86      |    2382     |
|  220  | 76      |    3548     |
|  220  | 86      |    3491     |
|  221  | 77      |    3550     |
|  221  | 87      |    2387     |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now What I want todo is to select the distinct reqIds that has both of the following

```
select * from t1 where 
(FIELDID='76' and LISTITEMID='3548')    
or (FIELDID='77' and LISTITEMID='3550') 
or ((FIELDID='86' and (LISTITEMID='3491' or LISTITEMID='2380')) 
or (FIELDID='87' and (LISTITEMID='3494' or LISTITEMID='2386'))) order by REQUIREMENTID
```

This gives me all rows that has any one of those above requirements. But what I want todo is to get

```
 select * from t1 where 
    ((FIELDID='76' and LISTITEMID='3548') or (FIELDID='77' and LISTITEMID='3550')) 
    and 
(((FIELDID='86' and (LISTITEMID='3491' or LISTITEMID='2380')) 
    or (FIELDID='87' and (LISTITEMID='3494' or LISTITEMID='2386')))) order by REQUIREMENTID
```

The above obviously don't return any rows. But it points to what I want todo.

What the query should return is **220** since thats the only rows that contain both FieldID=76 and ListItemId=3548 and fieldId=86 and listItemId=3491.

Is this easily done in a query or do I have to write two separate querys and then create 2 arrays and compare which ids that occurs in both arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. What you need to do is select all `Reqid` matching your conditions, and get all rows with that `Reqid`. This can be accomplished with a sub-query.

Done using two sub-queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE Reqid in 
(
    SELECT t11.Reqid 
    FROM t1 as t11
    WHERE 
        (t11.FIELDID='76' AND t11.LISTITEMID='3548') 
        OR (t11.FIELDID='77' AND t11.LISTITEMID='3550')
) 
AND Reqid in 
(
    SELECT t11.Reqid 
    FROM t1 as t11
    WHERE  
        (t11.FIELDID='86' AND (t11.LISTITEMID='3491' OR t11.LISTITEMID='2380')) 
        OR (t11.FIELDID='87' AND (t11.LISTITEMID='3494' OR t11.LISTITEMID='2386'))
)
ORDER BY REQUIREMENTID
```

This can further be translated into a single sub-query using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE Reqid in 
(
    SELECT t11.Reqid 
    FROM t1 as t11
    JOIN t1 as t12 on t11.Reqid = t12.Reqid
    WHERE 
        ((t11.FIELDID='76' AND t11.LISTITEMID='3548') OR (t11.FIELDID='77' AND t11.LISTITEMID='3550'))
        AND
        (
            (t12.FIELDID='86' AND (t12.LISTITEMID='3491' OR t12.LISTITEMID='2380')) 
            OR (t12.FIELDID='87' AND (t12.LISTITEMID='3494' OR t12.LISTITEMID='2386'))
        )
) 
ORDER BY REQUIREMENTID
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just do an `EXIST` statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ReqID
FROM
    t1 t
WHERE
    ((t.FIELDID = '76'
      AND t.LISTITEMID = '3548')
     OR (t.FIELDID = '77'
         AND t.LISTITEMID = '3550'))
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT
                    1
                 FROM
                    t1
                 WHERE
                    t1.Reqid = t.Reqid
                    AND ((t1.FIELDID = '86'
                          AND t1.LISTITEMID IN ('3491','2380'))
                         OR (t1.FIELDID = '87'
                             AND t1.LISTITEMID IN ('3494','2386'))))
```

Comment: I don't think you need 2 exist clauses, one of them can be moved to the where of the parent query

Comment: @FuzzyTree true!.. needed those aliases too.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is the AND, when what you need is a OR.

```
    select * from t1 where 
((FIELDID='76' and LISTITEMID='3548') or (FIELDID='77' and LISTITEMID='3550')) 
OR
(((FIELDID='86' and (LISTITEMID='3491' or LISTITEMID='2380')) 
or (FIELDID='87' and (LISTITEMID='3494' or LISTITEMID='2386')))) order by REQUIREMENTID
```